# Warning during powershell installation

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, windows-10, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I'm using below command for installing powerShell in VS code tool in a Windows 10 enterprise AVD.

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -Scope CurrentUser -force
```

However, getting warning,

```
  WARNING: The version '1.10.0' of module 
 'Microsoft.Graph.Authntication' is currently in use. Retry the 
 operation after closing this application.
```

How it is in use? Is the VS code tool using it for some internal operation? Will it affect the MS Graph functionality?

This type of message is keep on coming for all most all module with version '1.10.0'. I'm unable to get the other versions are getting installed or not. How do I know, when the installation is done? Its really confusing

How to install the latest Graph module perfectly?

Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for reaching out ,
After the installation is completed, you can verify the installed version with the following command.
Get-InstalledModule Microsoft.Graph

ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/installation?view=graph-powershell-1.0#verify-installation

Hope this helps thanks
please let us know if you have any query.

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please click "Accept Answer" and kindly upvote it. If you have extra questions about this answer, please click "Comment".